# Java RTFReader charset problems

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have an RTF File, that contains the escape character `\'80`, which should be the € symbol in my charset (using `\ansicpg1252` to set the codepage). Here is a minimal example Code:

```
String rtfWithEuro = "{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0 {\\fonttbl {\\f0 Times New Roman;}}\r\n"
            + "\\f0\\fs24 Hello, this is a Euro sign \\'80"
            + "\r\n}";
    
JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
tp.setContentType("text/rtf");
tp.setText(rtfWithEuro);
String result = tp.getDocument().getText(0, tp.getDocument().getLength());
```

Result should be `Hello this a Euro sign €`, but is `Hello this is a Euro sign Ђ`. The cyrillic letter `Ђ` has escape code `\'80` in codepage 1251, so it looks like java ignores the codepage.

Is there any way to tell a `JTextPane` which codepage to use?

Comment: Might be a related bug https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8186414